# Problem on saving data on server in android

Tags: android

Hello All I am sending signup data to server but when line of my code 
dos = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream()); encounters it throws an IOException "Permission Denied"
I have used the same code for another server before also and that time it worked fine.
I am not getting what is problem with this 
plz Help me
MY CODE IS 
try
          {

```
        URL                url;
```

//          URLConnection      urlConn; 
            DataOutputStream   dos; 
            DataInputStream    dis;

/---------------------THIS IS ADDRESS LINK WHERE WE HAVE TO SEND DATA------------***/
            String server_url_string = "http:----"signup.php";

```
        url = new URL(server_url_string);
```

//           urlConn =  url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

```
        urlConn.setDoInput(true); 

        urlConn.setDoOutput(true); 

        urlConn.setUseCaches(false); 

        urlConn.setRequestProperty ("METHOD", "POST");


        dos = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream());
```

/****-------------PREPARING STRING OF DATA TO BE SEND ON SERVER------------------***/

```
        String data_to_be_send = "signupdata=first_name="+first_name_str+":"+
                                 "oomplast_name="+last_name_str+":"+
                                 "oomppassword="+password_str+":"+
                                 "oompprimary_email="+email_str;


        Log.i("SERVER URL ",server_url_string);
        Log.i("SENDING DATA ",data_to_be_send);

        dos.writeBytes(data_to_be_send); 

        dos.flush(); 

        dos.close();
```

/** ------ The server responds by saying "Registration successfull." or "particular message or Invalid Data" -----*/

/**-------------------RETRIEVING MESSAGE CAME FROM SERVER----------------**/
            dis = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream()); 
            Log.i(" PASSED ","dis INITIALIZED");
            server_message = dis.readLine(); 
            Log.i(" PASSED ","server_message INITIALIZED");
            Log.i("SERVER RESPONSE",server_message+""); 
}
catch (MalformedURLException mue) 
          { 
              Log.i("EXCEPTION GENERATED MalformedURLException", " "+mue.getMessage());

```
      } 
      catch (IOException ioe) 
      { 
          Log.i("EXCEPTION GENERATED IOException ", " "+ioe.getMessage());
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your Android Manifest.

Comment: Thank You. It is embarrassing.